# How to redirect to axel when downloading and converting it via video downloadhelper

Tags: download-manager, axel

How do I redirect my download in axel when I am downloading and converting it via Video Downloadhelper.

In my currect setting in firefox, I downloaded Video DownloadHelper and Flashgot plugin.

My problem is that when I want to download and convert it to mp3 vidown downloadhelper uses built-in downloader even I already selected Axel as default downloader in its settings.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Michael Tunnell

I downloaded video downloadhelper because it has a built-in feature like Download and convert to MP3. That's why I need it. 

Any way thank you for your suggestion. I guess it's ok this way.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the conversion requires a built-in downloader to do the conversion.

What do you need Video Downloadhelper and Flashgot for? Flashgot can download files from sites like Youtube and such making the other addon unnecessary.

The problem is probably to conversion attempt while downloading...it would be much easier to just download the file and convert it after the fact with ffmpeg, winff, audacity, etc.

You could also use the site http://video2mp3.net that extracts the audio from a video and the provides a download of said audio.